# set the word 'remove' in text box in gui in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, matlab-guide

I programmed a GUI in Matlab (using guide). I have a text box in which I try to set strings. whenever I tried to put the string 'remove' using.

```
set(handles.sentence,'string','remove');
```

I get blank. if I put:

```
set(handles.sentence,'string','REMOVE');
```

it presents 'REMOVE' in the text box.

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [documented](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.text-properties.html):

> The words `default`, `factory`, and `remove` are reserved words that will not appear in text when quoted as a normal characters. To display any of these words individually, precede them with a backslash, such as `'\default'` or `'\remove'`.